# How to generate uuid inside the array.map in javascript?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, uuid

I am importing UUID like this

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
```

Inside the jsx
I am mapping the array and generating the random UUID for each item but
Its giving me error

```
{array.map((item) => (
   <View key={uuidv4()}>
     ...
   </View>
))}
```

Here is the error its giving me

[image]

Comment: See the link in your screenshot: https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid#getrandomvalues-not-supported  It explains how to fix the error!

Comment: Also, using cryptographicly secure uuids as random keys for React elements doesn't really make sense. If you really need a random value, something simpler based off of `Math.random()` will work fine. But I'm not sure you want a random key value really, that's not a very typical pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install --save react-native-get-random-values
npx pod-install


// Add this line to your `index.js`
import 'react-native-get-random-values'
```

For more info Refer: https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid#react-native--expo